# Move Configuration Apache to NGINX

Tags: nginx

I need your help with the following issues, I'm moving from apache to NGINX
and I need to do the following two issues I'm already doing on apache :

1. I need to redirect all the request from http to https, excluding a specific page.
   I added to the 80 and try to redirect all the request and not the product.html page but is not working

   ```
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  www.example.com;
       rewrite ~!.*/product.html https://$host$1 permanent;
   }
   ```
2. I have the following code:

   ```
   <Location ~ "/user/language/(\w+)/current">
       SetEnvIf Request_URI "/user/language/(\w+)/current$" CURRENT=$1
       Header append Set-Cookie "Path=/user/language/%{CURRENT}e;"
       Header edit Set-Cookie "^Path=/user/language/.*$" ""
   </Location>
   ```

I have no idea how to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Re: your issue #1 -- redirecting all requests to https except for the "product.html" page:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /path/to/your/web/root;

    location = /product.html {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }   

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }      
}
```

The above is straightforward. Use 2 location blocks -- one to match the exact page you *do not* want to redirect, and serve that page; the second one to match all requests starting with / (i.e. all requests) and redirect to *https*. The "product.html" page will match exactly in the first location block. All other requests fall through to the second block.

The nginx core module ("ngx_http_core_module") has examples on how to use location blocks using various regular expression and matching strings:

- [ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

Re: Your issue #2: You may want to study some examples on how to use *add_header* in nginx and test out your results, then come back and ask a separate question on details you have problems with. Here is the "ngx_http_headers_module" page in the nginx documation:

- [ngx_http_headers_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html)

There are a bunch of StackOverflow questions that provide details on how to set cookies. You might want to study those first. It's easier for others to help you answer your question if you can provide some code you have tried but perhaps didn't work.